# VBA assigning to array

Tags: vba

In the code snippet I create an array of string and want to assign it to another.

```
Dim rfms(0) As String
rfms(0) = "X"
```

The next line is not working

```
Me.SelectedRfms = rfms
```

But when I created the next function:

```
Function ReturnTheArrayInParamter(p() As String) As String()

    ReturnTheArrayInParamter = p

End Function
```

This is working:

```
Me.SelectedRfms = ReturnTheArrayInParamter(rfms)
```

The definition of Me.SelectedRfms is the next:

```
Private pSelectedRfms() As String

''''''''''''''''''''''
' SelectedRfms property
''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Property Get SelectedRfms() As String()
    SelectedRfms = pSelectedRfms
End Property
Public Property Let SelectedRfms(value() As String)
    pSelectedRfms = value
End Property
```

Can you explain why the first one is not working and why the second is working.

Comment: Can you include the results of: `VarType(rfms)` and `VarType(ReturnTheArrayInParamter(rfms))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an array declared with a fixed size to a property, use:

```
ReDim rfms(0) As String
```

(The indirect function does not use a fixed size array)